# ListView wont display date from database

Tags: android

With date save in MMM/dd/yyyy format in my database I cannot get a listView to populate with date, it works if I save date in dd/MM/yyyy or even MM/dd/yyyy

```
public class ListByDate extends ListActivity {

    DBAdapter myDB;
    String tag = "List By Date";




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.datelist);
        openDB();

        ArrayList<String> db_results = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor C = myDB.getDate();

        while (C.moveToNext()) {
            db_results.add(String.valueOf(C.getString(C
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_DATE))));
        }

        C.close();

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db_results));

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object date1 = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String dateClicked = date1.toString();





        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy");
        Date dateClick = null;
        try {
            dateClick = sdf.parse(dateClicked);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long da = dateClick.getTime();


        // Log to test clicks

        Log.v("List Item Click", dateClicked + " " + id + " " + position);




        Intent sd = new Intent(this, SelectedDate.class);
        sd.putExtra("seldate", dateClicked);
        sd.putExtra("selda", da);
        startActivity(sd);
        finish();

    }

    private void openDB() {
        myDB = new DBAdapter(this);
        myDB.open();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myDB.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        Log.i(tag, "Start Called");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        Log.i(tag, "Resume Called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        myDB.close();

        Log.i(tag, "Pause Called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        super.onStop();

        myDB.close();

        Log.i(tag, "Stop Called");
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to avoid is the order of the date in the listView
if I save dates to the database in the common date format in NZ(where i live) dd/MM/yyyy
the date will sort by dd, I want to sort by month
I dont want:

10/08/2014

10/09/2014

11/08/2014

11/09/2014

I thought using MMM dd yyyy(and Thanks XFactor for point out the / mistake) would solve this issue and not confuse people, 
If I use MM/dd/yyyy people from NZ could and probably would read 10/12/2014 as dd/MM/yyyy Dec 10 2014 and not Oct 12 2014

If I view my database, the date is stored MMM dd yyyy but the listView will open an empty list and as I said it works fine with dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: `MMM` abbreviated name of the month. And you are trying to show this way like `JUN/25/2012`? Which will be wrong. Generally you can use as `MMM dd yyyy`.

Comment: In which language is the date saved on the database?

Comment: You should save your date in the standard `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Comment: Yes @X'Factor, I would like to show it that way, the common date format in my country is dd/MM/yyyy which in a listView looks very messy, as the listView sorts the list by dd and not MM.

Comment: @Pedro the database is in english.

Comment: @Frank I dont really care how it is saved in database as long as I can manipulate the way it is displayed in the listView.

Comment: `I dont really care how it is saved in database` if you defined it as a **date** in the table, you have 2 possible formats for it: **integer** or **text**. Text accepts `yyyy-MM-dd` (date only) and `yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss`. You really **should care** about how you save your data into your db.

Comment: Its saved as text, and my comment was a little brash sorry, its not that I dont care its more I will change the way it is saved to solve this issue, thats what I mean when I say I dont care. everything will work fine if I use dd/MM/yyyy format.